# Playing with one Queen on a chessboard

Tags: strategy, checkerboard

Alice and Bob play a special chess game with alternate moves. Alics starts with an empty chessboard and puts a Queen at a field in the first row (A8-H8) or the right column (H1-H8). Now Bob is moving the Queen according to the chess rules, however with the following additional limitations:
1) A horizontal move is only allowed to the left
2) A vertical move is only allowed to the bottom
3) A diagonal move is only allowed to left bottom

Bob makes the first move.
The winner is the person, who placed the Queen at the bottom left corner (A1).

Who has a winning strategy?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean toward instead of to in the rules?  As I read them a vertical move must go all the way down to the first rank and a diagonal move is not allowed unless it ends at a1.  "to the left" can mean all the way to the left or in that direction.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We can work backwards to figure this out:

> The bottom left space is a winning space: if you place the queen there, you win.
>  [image]
>  So if you place the queen somewhere where the opponent *can* get to a winning space, you lose.
>  [image]
>  And if you place the queen somewhere where the opponent *must* move to a losing space, you win.
>  [image]
>  And if you place the queen somewhere where the opponent *can* move to a winning space, you lose.
>  [image]
>  ...and if your opponent *must* move to a losing space, you win...
>  [image]
>  ...and if your opponent *can* move to a winning space, you lose...
>  [image]
>  ...and if your opponent *must* move to a losing space, you win.
>  [image]

Conclusion:

> Alice can win the game by choosing to start on e8 (or h5); after that, on each of her turns she can always move to a green square, and Bob never can. So Alice will be the one to move to the bottom left corner and win.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen -- in fact pretty sure I've _answered_ -- a puzzle more or less equivalent to this one some time in the last year or thereabouts, but I can't find it at all...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yeah, I strongly suspected it was a duplicate as well but couldn't find the original.

Comment: Incidentally, for anyone curious about this game it's usually called rot13(Jlgubss'f tnzr) and the pattern of winning and losing positions has a nice mathematical property.

Comment: very nice presentation of the solution.. and very fast!

Comment: i think you have Bob and Alice reversed?  Bob moves first.

Comment: oh, never mind, the OP says it both ways....

Comment: Those are $9x9$ squares.

Comment: @PaulEvans Oh, of course. I'll fix it - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan There was a Riddler a few months back that used coins instead of a chessboard, but the math was the same: https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-many-pennies-should-you-pinch/

Comment: Ah! That could well be what I was thinking of. Thanks @EagleV_Attnam.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see if Bob's chances are any better if it is a King

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy, if I got this right on a quick drawing, with a King, the player placing the piece on the border, anywhere, loses. Also the pattern of losing and winning squares is much more boring, just a regular grid with two steps horizontally and vertically between the winning squares.

Answer (score 0):

Who ever plays first:

> Will win if they place the queen on e8 or h5 (followed by perfect play).

Because:

> a1, b3, c2, d6 and f4 are all winning squares that can be reached (only by the first player) after any 2nd, 4th or 6th move.